# EditText returning same value when activity is created again after the back button is pressed

Tags: java, android

That's my first post obviously here...okay so my problem is as follows:
@android: i have a TextEdit that a user enters in text, i get the text by getText() and it all works fine, but when i press the back button , and again come back to the same activity of the TextEdit and try to get the text again, it returns and empty string"" eventhough a different text is shown in the TextEdit view.
Could it be that the TextEdit is still "relating or corresponding" to the old closed activity?
Any ideas ?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.messaging_screen2);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgText);
    Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Go);
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           textToSend=editText.getText().toString();  
        }
    });

      }
```

Then in an AsynckTask i send the textToSend,

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        while(!done)
        {
            if(isCancelled())
            {
                done=true;
                break;
            }

            if(text.contains(Protocols.RESPONSE_OK))
               {
        System.out.println("getting message from edit text: "+textToSend);          
                publishProgress(textToSend);     
               }
        }           
        return null;            
    }
```

Now the when i can send msgs normally but when i press the back button and then start the same activity again, the FIRST msg sent is exactly the old one( upon pressing the send button for the first time ). when i press the send button again, the shown text in the EditText is sent properly.
so any help ?
Thanks.
After some debugging i noticed that the value of textToSend in send.Onclick() method is not the same as the one in the doInBackGround of the AsynckTask after creating the activity again. This happens on the first click of send, after witch everything works fine.

Comment: The exact problem is, after pressing the back button and restart the activity, the old value in the EditText is still stored by the getText(), even though the textEdit view shows a different value. My code is quite long. i am getting the text on a button click and processing it in an AsynckTask.

Answer (score 0):

Its weird, Paste your code,

Try set edittext.setText("test") in button's onClick() method. And check what return edittext.getText() when u back.

To change Activity use you this syntax?

```
Intent direction = new Intent(Class.this, DirectionClass.class);   
startActivity(direction);
```

Comment: I start my activity as follows: `Intent mIntent= new Intent("android.intent.action.MSGSCRN2");
startActivity(mIntent);`